# No water in shower

Tags: bathroom-fixtures

We have replaced the water cartridge in the shower because of low water pressure, now we have no water coming out of it. We have tried seeing if it was upside down. And no change... please help

Comment: You really need to supply more information such as the make and model of your cartridge and the fixture. Photographs would also greatly aid the quality of any answers to your problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You did turn on the shut off valve after replacement, didn't you?  Have done that a few times.

Comment: Yes we turned the water back on.. thanks

Comment: Low pressure and now no water probably a blockage in the pipe/s.  Is it both hot and cold?  Turn off water, remove cartridge and slowly turn shut off back on.  Prepare to turn off again.

Comment: Where there any blanking plugs that needed to be removed from the cartridge before fitting?